# No route to host error trying a telnet from a CentOS 7 to another CentOS 7

Tags: networking, centos, routing, firewall, centos-7

I have two CentOS 7 machines on a same VLAN (on the external network firewall there are not blocking rules for machines on the same VLAN).

The problem is that it seems that from one of these machine I can't contact a port on the second machine:

```
[root@MY-MACHINE config]# telnet 192.168.130.6 55000
Trying 192.168.130.6...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.130.6: No route to host
```

Where **MY-MACHINE** have IP: **192.168.130.5** and it is located on the same VLAN.

So what could blocking this connection?

Can there be a local firewall rule on my 192.168.130.6 machine?

What checks can I do?

Comment: There can be many reasons. Without knowing a thing about your network configuration, it's hard to say anything. To start with something, provide at least outputs from the following commands: `netstat -r -n`, `ifconfig -a` and `iptables -L -n`. Don't know if this will be enough, but at least it's some information to start with.

Comment: And are you able to `ping` the target machine?

Comment: Which protocol using the port 55000 serving ? Is it TCP/ UDP or any other ?